# How put the last changed object at the end of array with an optimum way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects... each object has a boolean key called 'included' changed when clicking on a button in html
I need the array to be sorted the objects with true value on the top and then the objects with false value including that the last changed object with false value put at the last of array and if changed to true put after the objects with truthy value

the below is what I did ... is that optimum or there ara another way?

```
 <mat-icon *ngIf="product.included" 
                  (click)="applyAction('exclude', product.id)">
                    remove
                  </mat-icon>
                  <mat-icon *ngIf="!product.included" 
                  (click)="applyAction('include', product.id)">
                    add
                  </mat-icon>
```

```
  applyAction(action: action, id: number): void {
    const selectedProduct = this.productTypes.find((i) => i.id === id);
    if (action === 'exclude') {
      selectedProduct.included = false;
    } else {
      selectedProduct.included = true;
    }
    this.productTypes = this.productTypes.filter((i) => i.id !== id);
    this.productTypes.push(selectedProduct);
    this.productTypes.sort((a, b) => Number(b.included) - Number(a.included));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about optimum but you could use [`.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and use [`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) remove the element and then do a [`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to push the latest edited element to the end:

```js
let productTypes = [{id: 1, included: true}, {id: 2, included: false}, {id: 3, included: true}];

const applyAction = (action, id) => {
  const selectedProductIdx = productTypes.findIndex((i) => i.id === id);
  const selectedProduct = productTypes[selectedProductIdx];
  if (action === 'exclude') {
    selectedProduct.included = false;
  } else {
    selectedProduct.included = true;
  }
  productTypes.splice(selectedProductIdx, 1);
  productTypes.push(selectedProduct);
}

applyAction('exclude', 1);
applyAction('include', 2);
console.log(productTypes);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say use one temporary array and push all the element except the particular last updated id element and end of the function push the last updated id element. It will took O(n) time and space.

```
applyAction(action: action, id: number): void {
   let findInd = -1, temp_arr=[];
   this.productTypes.forEach((element, index)=>{
        if(element.id !=id) temp_arr.shift(element);
        else findInd = index;
   });
   temp_arr.push(this.productTypes[findInd]);
   this.productTypes = temp_arr;
}
```